# Hide some page from wp admin - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I m working on a wordpress plugin where there are some function that get values from db and programmatically create a page. Every page that s created, i would like hide from wp admin. What is the correct function for this case ?
PS I stock in array the id of pages.

Comment: there is a guide for a function for it here, which you can rewrite with your array of post ids : https://divilife.com/knowledge-base/hide-page-wordpress-admin-users/

Comment: and here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13554/82677

Comment: hi, how can i replace "=array()" with a variable array? cause i get this error "ser_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'mic_hide_pages_in_wp_admin' not found or invalid function name in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 287"